# Oracle optional filter where (this date set) or (that date set)

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, filter, jasper-reports

I have two sets of date ranges with which I may filter by - date set A and date set B.

I need my query to work as follows:
If date set A is null, use date set B.
If date set B is null, use date set A.

Both date sets are parameters that get passed to the query. Either set can be passed but not both together.

Both date sets are columns in the same table. Date set A would filter according to column A in the table and date set B would filter according to column B.

My understanding is that a case is required within the where clause but I simply can't seem to get it right - probably because my PL/SQL knowledge is lacking.

This is the closest I could get:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE dateA <= (CASE WHEN $P{to_dateA} IS NULL THEN current_date ELSE to_date($P{to_dateA}) END) 
AND dateA >= (CASE WHEN $P{from_dateA} IS NULL THEN current_date ELSE to_date($P{from_dateA}) END) 
AND dateB <= (CASE WHEN $P{to_dateB} IS NULL THEN current_date ELSE to_date($P{to_dateB}) END) 
AND dateB >= (CASE WHEN $P{from_dateB} IS NULL THEN current_date ELSE to_date($P{from_dateB}) END)
```

Comment: Please post your complete stored procedure

Comment: I've edited my question according to your comment. All that I have got working is checking if each value is null, if so, return the current date and filter according to current date... 
`SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE dateA <= (CASE WHEN $P{to_dateA} IS NULL THEN current_date
ELSE to_date($P{to_dateA})
END)
AND dateA >= (CASE WHEN $P{from_dateA} IS NULL THEN current_date
ELSE to_date($P{from_dateA})
END)
AND dateB <= (CASE WHEN $P{to_dateB} IS NULL THEN current_date
ELSE to_date($P{to_dateB})
END)
AND  dateB >= (CASE WHEN $P{from_dateB} IS NULL THEN current_date
ELSE to_date($P{from_dateB})
END)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE (a IS NULL AND b BETWEEN lower_b_date AND upper_b_date)
    OR (b IS NULL AND a BETWEEN lower_a_date AND upper_a_date)
```